# Naive Bayes Assignment of Feature Probability

Tags: probability, naive-bayes, nltk

I'm using the .show_most_informative_features() function from NLTK's Naive Bayes  to generate features to be used with a lexicon. In the case of my binary-classification problem, these features are calculated as (where W = feature and V = class):
$$
MAX(P(W|V^1) / P(W|V^2)
$$

I just want to make sure that I understand how NLTK's NB calculates the probability of a feature belonging to a particular class. Essentially, I need someone to inform me how this is calculated:

$$
P(W|V^i)
$$

I believe the type of NB NLTK uses is MultiNomial. An explanation sourced from this [stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkMpY.gif) post:

> The probability of a word given the tag is computed in the train() function using the Expected Likelihood Estimation from the ELEProbDist which is a LidstoneProbDist object under the hood where the gamma argument is set to 0.5, and it does:
>
> class LidstoneProbDist(ProbDistI):
>
> "The Lidstone estimate for the probability distribution of the
>       experiment used to generate a frequency distribution.  The
>       "Lidstone estimate" is parameterized by a real number *gamma*,
>       which typically ranges from 0 to 1.  The Lidstone estimate
>       approximates the probability of a sample with count *c* from an
>       experiment with *N* outcomes and *B* bins as
>       `c+gamma)/(N+B*gamma)`.  This is equivalent to adding
>       *gamma* to the count for each bin, and taking the maximum
>       likelihood estimate of the resulting frequency distribution."

How is this explanation represented as a step-by-step mathematical process?

[Detailed explanation on stack.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017288/how-is-most-informative-feature-percentage-is-calculated-in-naive-bayes-nltk-pyt)
[NLTK NB documentation.](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html)
[NLTK Probability documentation.](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L734)

Sample Output:

```
Most Informative Features
             outstanding = 1                 pos : neg    =     13.9 : 1.0
               insulting = 1                 neg : pos    =     13.7 : 1.0
              vulnerable = 1                 pos : neg    =     13.0 : 1.0
               ludicrous = 1                 neg : pos    =     12.6 : 1.0
             uninvolving = 1                 neg : pos    =     12.3 : 1.0
              astounding = 1                 pos : neg    =     11.7 : 1.0
```

Comment: Whats the point of downvoting if you're not going to tell me what I've done incorrectly?

Comment: I agree; I will upvote to cancel the downvote. I believe there is some value to this question. I may be able to pull an answer to this later this weekend.